# Can memory mapped file be loaded faster into RAM?

Tags: c#, memory, byte, memory-mapping

I have 256GB of RAM and 200GB file that I'm fully loading into RAM on windows 11.
I'm using C# and .net core memory mapping and unsafe pointers.
I map the big file to an address space and then access the addresses in a linear sequence to read from it from low address to high address, while I'm doing that windows OS is loading the pages to RAM. however this is super slow about 250MB/s, my SSD drive can do at least 2GB/s.
After the first time load finishes, any subsequent memory scans are super fast coz all data is in RAM.

Is there any trick to speed up the loading process?

Comment: "Is there any trick to speed up the loading process?" -- sure, compression. You even have DirectStorage to decompress files using the GPU available in Win11.

Comment: ^ but test both ways, the decompression might be slower than raw I/O on a fast nvme SSD if the CPU (or GPU) can't decompress fast enough, especially if the data is not highly compressible.  If the data is encrypted on disk, compress before encrypting since encrypted data is often much less compressible,.

Comment: I personally do not think you need compression. Try to look to buffer size options. It looks like you do IO by small blocks.

Comment: 1) I can't use compression coz the data is almost random
2) I'm talking about memory mapped files, I'm not doing any IO reading myself, the OS does that part and it does it very slowly.

Comment: Are you still using .net Framework?   I have not tested this on .net Core, but at least on .net Framework, memory mapped files worked very slowly. I ditched the built-in classes in favor of  memory mapped files accesed via a C++/CLI library (directly calling the Win32 memory-mapped file APIs) access became blazing fast. I also spawned an aux thread that touched every page while the worker thread processed the files sequentially,  a sort of prefetch thread, this also sped things up nicely.